# According to Ohm's Law, shouldn't there be a zero electric potential within a capacitor since the current is 0?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

If V = I*R, then how does a capacitor store electric potential? The current across a capacitor is 0.

Comment: The formula $V=IR$ applies to resistors only. Also, the current through a capacitor is not always zero. The direct current (i.e. zero frequency) current is zero, but the ac current is not zero. Finally, we do not need current to have electric potential. Current is the flow of charge, while potential is the difference in energy of a charge in one place or another. The two terminals of a battery have different potential even when there's no current flowing.

Comment: So Ohm's law is only a specific case of voltage?

Comment: @Goldname, capacitors do not obey Ohm's 'Law'.  A device that obeys Ohm's law is an ohmic device.  Ohm's law is not a specific case of voltage, it is a specific case of a voltage - current relationship.

Comment: Voltage means "energy difference between two points, per amount of charge". In other words, given a charge $q$, the energy it takes to move that charge from point $A$ to point $B$ is $V_b - V_a$. It is not specific to resistors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohm's law applies to any system through which a steady current is flowing (life gets more complicated when the current is changing with time). In principle it applies to a capacitor because in any real capacitor the dielectric isn't a perfect insulator so there will be a very small current flowing.

Ohm's law tells us:

$$ V = I R $$

where in a real capacitor $I$ is very small and $R$ is very large. Multiplying together the very small and very large numbers gives us the voltage $V$.

In an ideal capacitor $I=0$ and $R=\infty$, and our equation becomes:

$$ V = 0 \times \infty $$

But this equation makes no sense because we cannot do arithmetic with $\infty$.

Comment: Saying Ohm's law applies to any system through which current is flowing is suspect... It's not immediately obvious how this applies to inductors, with $V=L\frac{dI}{dt}$.

Comment: Hmm, yes, OK. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In case of capacitors we measure the potential difference like the following:

If the charge in capacitor is $Q$ and capacitance is $C$ then $V= Q/C$. Ohm's law is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Hi first_overtone and welcome to Physics.SE! Please see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) help post to learn how to write your equations in a way nicer way i.e. in $\LaTeX$, in order to improve legibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm d}\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$You need to get a bigger picture in order to understand why you cannot apply Ohm's law to a capacitor. First of all Ohm's law is a phenomenological law i.e. someone goes into a lab and tests tons of resistances with tons of different batteries and finds out that for a good approximation $\Delta V=IR$  holds. That is the potential difference on either side of the resistance is $IR$. Note that this is not quite the Ohm's law you know, which states $V_0=IR$, where $V_0$ is the DC voltage source. Note that if the resistance gets too hot ie. if the current is too high the law breaks down as the properties of the material, from which the resistance is made of changes.

For a capacitor you cannot apply Ohm's law because a capacitor is not a ohm-resistance. You need to apply the Faraday's law of induction:

$$\oint_{\partial\Sigma} \vec E \cdot \d \vec l = - \pdv{} t \int_\Sigma \vec B \cdot \d \vec A  := - \pdv {\Phi_B} t$$

in plain English the closed loop integral around some boundary $\partial \Sigma$ is equal to the minus of the change of the magnetic flux $\Phi_B$ in time.

For a circuit, which has a resistance $R$ and a battery $V_0$ the closed loop integral gives, if you choose your boundary to be the circuit itself:

$$\oint \vec E \cdot \d \vec l = V_0 - IR $$

Since $\pdv{\Phi_B} t = 0$ you get

$$V_0 - IR = 0 \iff V_0 = IR$$

If we have a capacitor with capacitance $C$ and a DC voltage source $V_0$ after the capacitor is "fully" charged we get with $\pdv{\Phi_B} t= 0$:

$$ V_0 - \frac CQ = 0 \implies V_0 = \frac C Q $$

Note that I've used the phenomenological law $\Delta V = C/Q$ to get the voltage drop across the capacitor.